# How to change status with ajax in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using laravel project and I have a shopping cart.

I want to send number of the product to method name quantity with ajax and give it as a request but it gives me this error

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

here is my route

```
Route::post('/user-cart/{shop}/{userID}/quantity-change/{id}', 'CartController@quantity')->middleware('auth')->name('quantity');
```

**My controller:**

```
public function quantity(Request $request){

    dd($request->all());
}
```

this is my numbers option

```
<td>

    <select class="c-ui-select js-ui-select" id="expressShipping-count-0" autocomplete="off" tabindex="-1">
        <a href="#"><option value="1">۱</option></a>
        <option value="2">۲</option>
        <option value="3">۳</option>
        <option value="4" selected="">۴</option>
        <option value="5">۵</option>
    </select>

</td>
```

here is my ajax

```js
$(function(){
 $('#expressShipping-count-0').on('change', function(){
     var value = $(this).val();
     console.log(value);
         $.ajax({
           type:'post',
             url: "{{url('/user-cart/digikala/7/quantity-change/1')}}",
             data: {
                 value: value,
                 "_token": $('#csrf-token')[0].content //pass the CSRF_TOKEN()
             },
             success: function(data) {
                 var url = document.location.origin + "/user-cart/{shop}/{userID}/quantity-change/{id}";
                 location.href = url;
             }
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: Where are you getting `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.` error ? in ajax response or on page redirection ?

Comment: It seems that your ajax request works fine. Do you have a GET route for your redirect?

Comment: remove the {id}  and put it as POST variable sended by ajax

Comment: @Vibha Chosla after click on number for send it I think ajax is ok because whenever I open url directly it gives me same error without ajax

Comment: @Ali Khalili yes it works fine.. no

Comment: this is because you don't have a GET method in your `web.php` for your page redirection url

Comment: @Melvita  same error

Comment: @Vibha Chosla I remove the redirect part of that but I can not see my request->all() in page like this : http://localhost:8000/user-cart/digikala/7/quantity-change/1

Comment: this is because you have declared `post ` route in your `web.php` and accessing it via `GET`  method, so that will not access directly hitting url in browser.

Comment: For testing you can convert `Route::post('/user-` to `Route::get('/user-` and check the `dd()` response directly hitting url in browser

Comment: @Vibha Chosla clearly it works with get method but I want to change something when customer select number I just want to send that number with request

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change your `Route` and use `any` method instead of `post`.

```
Route::any('/user-cart/{shop}/{userID}/quantity-change/{id}', 'CartController@quantity')->middleware('auth')->name('quantity');
```

Try this..

Comment: it shows page like empty , I want my request on that page

Comment: @hassankhosro if you run `http://localhost:8000/user-cart/digikala/7/quantity-change/1` any error happen?

Comment: with any method no just gives me [ ] on dd()

Comment: @hassankhosro So as your functionality doesn't need to redirect URL in ajax request. When you select any number it will automatically ajax run and then you need to manage request in the controller.

Answer (score -1):

As the rest of the friends said Problem was for redirect action
so thanks to everyone